# Sinatra: modular routes class not recognizing helper methods

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rackup

I am building an API in Sinatra, and have converted to a modular style. However, I am having an issue with method calls inside the routes files not being recognized.

I have simplified the app so the post is shorter, but the basic problem is that if I `GET /test` in `WorkoutHandler` - it cannot recognize methods in `WardenStrategies` or `LoginHelper` unless I also include those files in the Handler (they are already included in app.rb). However once I do that, the methods declared in the gems they use are unrecognized. All of these are registered in app.rb, and are required in my Rackup file.

Here is my app.rb file

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'

class WorkoutApp < Sinatra::Base

  register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension
  register WardenStrategies

  use WorkoutHandler

  helpers LoginHelper
  helpers HashHelpers

  use Rack::Session::Cookie
  use Warden::Manager do |manager|
    manager.default_strategies :password
    manager.intercept_401 = false
    manager.failure_app = WorkoutApp
    manager.serialize_into_session(&:id)
    manager.serialize_from_session { |id| User.find(id) }
  end
  set :database_file, '../config/database.yml'

  Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, _opts|
    env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'
  end
end
```

Here are the config.ru, Handler, and Helper files. (Handlers are just the name I use for Controller/Route files.

```
module LoginHelper
  def warden_handler
    env['warden']
  end

  def current_user
    warden_handler.user
  end

  def check_authentication
    return if warden_handler.authenticated?
    body 'User not authenticated'
    halt 401
  end
end
```

---

I was under the assumption that `helpers`, `use`, and `register` only need to be declared in app.rb (since I require all files in my rackup file and run the app from there). However the `check_authentication` method isn't recognized unless I register the helper here as well.

```
class WorkoutHandler < Sinatra::Base
  helpers LoginHelper                   # Is there a way to not need this?
  register WardenStrategies             # Or this?

  get '/test' do
    check_authentication
  end
end
```

---

```
module WardenStrategies
  Warden::Strategies.add(:password) do
    def valid?
      params['email'] || params['password']
    end

    def authenticate!
      user = User.find_by(email: params['email'])
      if user && user.authenticate(params['password'])
        success!(user)
      else
        fail!('Could not log in')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require     #Shouldn't this give my Handler access to gem methods?

ENV['APP_NAME'] = 'workout'

require_all 'app'

run WorkoutApp
```

As of the time of this writing, I am getting the following error when running specs:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticated?' for nil:NilClass
```

This means that env doesn't have a :warden key/value (which I confirmed in console). The `authenticated?` method is in the Warden gem directory, so I guess I could `require 'warden'` in each Handler file - I don't think that's the way modular Sinatra apps are supposed to be constructed.

I've read all the blog posts and book chapters I can find on modular Sinatra apps, and I can't seem to debug my issue. From what I understand, needing to re-register (include) helpers in all files that use them is extraneous. I thought that by extending Sinatra::Base, I would have access to all declared classes in app.rb.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that every time you subclass Sinatra::Base, it creates a completely independent Sinatra application. Just because multiple classes subclass Sinatra::Base doesn't mean they all inherit each others' attributes. This is why it's called a "modular" style!

If you have some common functionality to be shared between different Sinatra applications, you can either create a mixin and extend/include it in every application (which is basically what you're doing now with `helpers` and `register`), or you can create an intermediate class that your applications subclass. For example:

my_base_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'warden'

require_relative 'login_helper'

class MyBaseApp < Sinatra::Base
  register WardenStrategies

  helpers LoginHelper
end
```

workout_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'warden'

require_relative 'my_base_app'
require_relative 'hash_helpers'
require_relative 'workout_handler'

class WorkoutApp < MyBaseApp
  register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension

  use WorkoutHandler

  helpers HashHelpers

  use Rack::Session::Cookie
  use Warden::Manager do |manager|
    # yadda yadda...
  end
end
```

workout_handler.rb:

```
require_relative 'my_base_app'

class WorkoutHandler < MyBaseApp
  get '/test' do
    check_authentication
  end
end
```

As far as your question "Shouldn't this give my Handler access to gem methods?" that depends on how your Gemfile is laid out. If you have something like this:

```
gem 'sinatra', :require => 'sinatra/base'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', :require => 'sinatra/activerecord'
gem 'warden'
```

Then yes, doing `Bundle.require` in your rackup script would eliminate the need to do individual `require` statements in your class files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does config.ru `run WorkoutApp` or `run MyBaseApp`?

Comment: Based on what you know about Ruby classes, what do you think? :-) Does a parent class automatically include all its subclasses?

Comment: No because a subclass could redefine a method in its parent class.

Comment: Right. You want the app to start with WorkoutApp, pull in the stuff from its parent, MyBaseApp, and insert the WorkoutHandler middleware. So rackup WorkoutApp and you should be all set.